# Get started with Postgres in ubuntu(14.04) with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to start learning postgres in I've spent(wasted) 6-7 hours in figuring out that how to start.

there are so many tutorials/blog etc but still not getting exactly what should I do.

to be specific I'm still trying to use this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04

```
eric@eric:~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib # succesfully installed version 9.3.5
eric@eric:~$ psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
eric@eric:~$ sudo -i -u postgres   # switch to user postgres
postgres@eric:~$
```

now I tried to create db with `createdb` command and some other stuff. but I think I got stuck in mess.
when I tried to change password for this user it says

```
postgres@eric:~$ sudo passwd postgres
[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

I just want to create a new user(with password) and a DB associated with this.

could somebody explain the main concept and commands for setting up these
(able to use this script)
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_python.htm

Comment: are you confusing system users with postgres users?  `postgres` is the name of a system user, and `passwd` changes the password for a system user.

Comment: No! I understand that. but not the complete flow. why do we even need a separate user for a DB (unlike MySQL or some other NoSQL DB)
What if I create another user.Role and user are same in postgres?

Comment: running each system service as its own user is generally a good idea.  to make a new user, just run `createuser` as the `postgres` user.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the password for the `postgres` system user in the first place? Please read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL . You seem to be confusing `postgres` users with system users.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I'm not trying to set password for postgres. but I just want to be create another user(Role? are both same?) and a DB for this user. most importantly I should be able to use psycopg2 library. can you please help me in this by providing steps for ubuntu.because I think my postgres concepts are not clear as I'm newbie to postgres

Comment: @xyz The link above covers it, along with the postgresql tutorial. If anything is unclear feel free to comment.

Comment: @CraigRinger: would be grateful if you can explain basic concepts in depth. like what is role/user. how postgres user is different from unix user? are they? a basic setup(a user/role, a db and makeing queries) from the beginning can clear my concepts.
can you write a small document(1-2 page pdf/doc/txt) for me. that would be very helpful. or just write that content here in answer box.

Comment: @xyz Did you read the tutorial? It covers most of that. If it doesn't, then we need to improve the tutorial! http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html  . A postgres user is *completely unrelated* to an OS user, except that if they share the same name and you have 'peer' auth enabled PostgreSQL will trust that an OS user has the right to log in to the corresponding PostgreSQL user. If you have *specific questions* not covered by the tutorial and the Ubuntu community documentation I'm interested, but I'm not just going to rewrite the existing docs to cover the same stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **psql** ?

postgres@eric:~$ psql

postgres# create role USERNAME with LOGIN; 
postgres# \password USERNAME      -- \password is recommend way to change passwords in postgresql

set password
confirm password

play little bit with grants a bit
hint: by default all public member can login to database,
      but you need to grant actions on tables for users